# Show entries dropdown disappear when using export tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Show entries dropdown disappear when using export tools

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip', // if you remove this line you will see the show entries dropdown
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p33x5L3t/)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You just lack the `l` flag in `dom`. `l` for "length changing input control".

```
dom: 'lBfrtip'
```

will make the dropdown to reappear.

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/p33x5L3t/1/**
`dom` documentation -> **https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom**

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! One question - when using your fix, the buttons do reappear, but they are quite close to the "show entries dropdown" ... what is a good way to add some padding/space between the end of the word "entries" and the first export button (Copy)?

Comment: Do I need to perhaps edit the datatables button CSS file? (I'm fairly new to these things, sorry if my questions are stupid)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, It depends a little of the kind of styling you use. I.e default built in, bootstrap, foundation etc.  You could just add spacing to the button container `.dt-buttons {  margin-left: 50px; }` **https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/2/** or wrap buttons into a styled container like `dom: 'l<".margin" B>frtip'` **https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/3/**

Comment: I am using the default buttons cdn [here](https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css) but I think if I want to change it, the two problems are that it is a minified file and impossible to read, second that it is hosted on their website

Comment: So, I think I should first [unminify the file](http://unminify.com/), host it on my own site and change the style reference link in the html file, then I can put in whatever I want and hopefully it works?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I think it sounds to be way too much effort :) And you will really regret the day you want to update. You can simply just override CSS declarations if you need, just declare them after the CSS import. Use the browsers inspector do figure out what declarations you need to target. See the fiddles above, the first is overriding a CSS declaration.

Comment: OK, I included the CSS code from your first fiddle link within the style tag of the html file, and it worked perfectly! Thank you again :)

Comment: Thanks@davidkonrad it works like charm after I keep the line of code in my js file.

Answer (score 23):

I know it is too long, but if some one still facing this issue, then please do the following, it is an alternate answer.

Add 'pageLength' inside buttons as follows:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'pageLength','copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
      dataTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
         "processing":true,
         "serverSide":true,
          dom:'lBfrtip',
          buttons: ['excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'copy'],
         "lengthMenu": [50,100,500,1000,2000,5000,10000,50000,100000],
         "order":[],
         "sScrollX": "100%",
         "scrollCollapse": true,
         "ajax":{
            url:"FetchAllAjax.php",
            type:"POST"
         }
      });       
   });
```